# How I create a separate command to copy from my tmux clipboard to my Linux clipboard?

Tags: linux, tmux, clipboard

I am trying to emulate the following bindings that work in OSX in Linux:

```
# Copy and paste from system clipboard
bind C-c run "tmux save-buffer - | reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy"
bind C-v run "reattach-to-user-namespace pbpaste | tmux load-buffer - && tmux paste-buffer"
```

That is, I want to bind a command to explicilty copy the tmux buffer into my system clipboard and a different command to copy back. I **do not** want to automatically use vi-select to copy to my system clipboard from tmux, as many of the [existing answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131187/34334) address.

I have tried the following bindings (one at a time).

```
bind C-c run "tmux save-buffer - | xclip -in -selection clipboard"
bind C-c run "tmux show-buffer | xclip -sel clip -i"
```

Both of them appear to do the right thing on first use, but then have a serious side effect: Disabling all my tmux keybindings after use.

That is, none of my tmux keybindings work after the first copy.

**How can I copy something from my tmux clipboard to my system clipboard and vice versa explicitly without disabling my ability to run further tmux commands?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xclip has a bug where it does not close stdout, which means tmux doesn't know it has finished. This is why you can't run any further tmux commands after the first time you copy. So you can either:

1) Use xsel instead of xclip which does not suffer from the same problem.

2) Redirect stdout to `/dev/null` like this: `xclip ... >/dev/null`

3) Use `run -b` instead of `run` so tmux doesn't wait for xclip to finish.